# gem install fails with "Could not find a valid gem 'yaml'"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm building a gem from a *currently working* ruby program. It's using jruby 1.7.12 and, among other things, does a "require 'yaml". For the gem, my Gemfile contains:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gemspec
```

When I run

```
gem build program.gemspec
```

that works just fine, but when I run

```
gem install program-0.15.01.gem
```

it fails with

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'yaml' (>= 0) in any repository 
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: aml, cyaml, haml, maml, raml
```

Doesn't make any sense since the yaml module is part of the ruby 1.9.3 standard library.

I've upgraded to the latest rubygems (2.4.5).

What the heck am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`yaml` is part of Ruby. There is no `yaml` gem (see https://rubygems.org/search?query=yaml).

Therefore remove

```
s.add_runtime_dependency 'yaml'
```

from your `gemspec` and just add `require 'yaml'` to the file in which you want to use `YAML`.